# Error in Doctrine Migrations

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, migration

I am using symfony (2.6.9) and doctrine in a old project. When I start to work here I realize that some of the migrations were executed and then deleted for history. So I can't not replicate the current state of production database. So create a database backup from production and install it in my local enviroment. Then when I try to execute new migrations with symfony.I get an error when I execute this query:

`'ALTER TABLE video_en ADD CONSTRAINT FK_65A1A65C1B53C8FE FOREIGN KEY (portuguese_id) REFERENCES video_pt (id) ON DELETE SET NULL'`

I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'publication_date' at row 1
```

I think that the problem is related to old data in the database. So, I want to execute migrations in production and keep all the data.

Good to know is that if I executed migrations in a clean enviroment. It is working ( But as I write in the first paragraph, in production there are executed some migrations that are not in the code ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the structure of your table, I can only guess. Based on what you've posted here however, IF that IS the migration command causing that error, there can only be one cause:

Column: video_en.publication_date at some point was storing datetimes in another format, and a migration failed to properly change the dates from one format to another.

Whether you're in [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) or [sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql), '0000...' is not a valid date. However, int 0, null, and malformed dates, will often be forced to be stored as this when converting them to a datetime.

Fixing this problem should be as simple as running a bulk update against the table:

```
UPDATE video_en SET publication_date = '2017-08-28' WHERE publication_date = < '1970-01-01';
```

Comment: I set as correct because you give me the idea but problem persist if I execute your proposal query, I mean I get the same error because I can not also use this date "00:00:00" to compare so from your idea I decided to execute this query:

UPDATE video_en SET publication_date = "1970-01-01" WHERE publication_date < "1970-01-01

And now I can execute migrations.

Comment: updated answer to reflect your findings. should be able to set time to 0's, but you are correct about the where clause. That never would have worked the way I had it. Thank you, and happy coding!